# Как сделать выборку элеменов с XPATH кроме первого и последнего

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, xpath

У меня есть HTML список:

```
<div class="breadscrumbs">
    <ul class="items">
       <li class="item home">1</li>
       <li class="item category****">2</li>
       <li class="item product>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Тегов li может быть сколько угодно, но не меньше трех. Вместо звездочек могут быть символы. Надо с помощью XPATH получить все кроме первого и последнего. Можно использовать регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python не знаю, но XPath будет такой:

`//ul[@class='items']/li[position()>1 and position()<last()]`

Answer (score 2):

1 Вариант:

```
browser.get_elements_by_xpath( "//li[contains(@class, 'item')]")[1:-1]
```

2 Вариант:

```
"//li[contains(@class, 'item ') and position()>1 and position()<last()]"
```